# JSF Validation not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces

My following code is not working as per expectation. The validation does not work as expected.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>My Registration Page</title>
    <link href="stylesheet/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.png" />
    <script src="script/script.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText id="progress_bar" styleClass="progress-bar" /> 
    <a4j:jsFunction name="login" action="#{loginBean.validateUser}" />


    <div id="login-container">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <f:view>
            <div id="loin-form">
                <h1>
                    Log in to your account or <a href="#">sign up</a> to Get Started
                </h1>
                <h:form>
                    <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginBean.userName}"
                        label="User Name" required="true" class="txtFld">
                        <f:validator
                            validatorId="com.coinfling.validation.LoginBeanValidator" />
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="userName" style="color:red"></h:message>
                    <h:inputSecret id="passWord" value="#{loginBean.passWord}"
                        label="Password" required="true" class="pswrdFld">
                        <f:validator
                            validatorId="com.coinfling.validation.LoginBeanValidator" />
                    </h:inputSecret>
                    <h:message for="passWord" style="color:red"></h:message>
                    <p>
                        <a4j:commandLink id="forgotPasswordLink" lable="Password"
                            value="Forgot Your Password? " />
                        <a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In"
                            onclick="login();" styleClass="sign-btn" />
                    </p>
                </h:form>
            </div>


        </f:view>
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

My simple validation class code is below
package com.coinfling.validation;

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
@FacesValidator("com.coinfling.validation.LoginBeanValidator")
public class LoginBeanValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("*UserName is not in Correct Format");
        throw new ValidatorException(message);

//      
//      if(toValidate.getId().equals("userName"))
//      {
//          FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("*UserName is not in Correct Format");
//          throw new ValidatorException(message);
//      }
//      else if(toValidate.getId().equals("passWord"))
//      {
//          FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("*Password is not in Correct Format");
//          throw new ValidatorException(message);
//      }
    }

}
```

As you can see my validation i am just thrown an exception for whatever gets input. The required field is also not working. No error message is printed. What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually submitting the form. You're basically invoking a standalone bean method separately. That's a huge difference. To execute validation on the form, you have to submit the form.

Replace the wrong `a4j:jsFunction` approach:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="login" action="#{loginBean.validateUser}" />
...
<a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In"
   onclick="login();" styleClass="sign-btn" />
```

by the normal form submit approach:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In"
   action="#{loginBean.validateUser}" styleClass="sign-btn" />
```

I'm not sure why you used `a4j:jsFunction`, but whatever you thought to benefit from the `a4j:jsFunction`, has definitely to be solved in a different way.

Don't forget to add a `render="@form"` to update the form on complete of the ajax request, so that all messages are been shown:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In"
   action="#{loginBean.validateUser}" render="@form" styleClass="sign-btn" />
```

Comment: Assuming that you mean with "not working" that the neither the validation nor the action method is ever invoked (as confirmed by the debugger), then the problem is caused elsewhere than visible in the code posted so far, combined with the changes in the answer posted so far. First of all, is a HTTP request actually been sent according the webbrowser's developer toolset? Can you successfully submit a Hello World JSF form?

Comment: My validator is working as i have a debug line in there, and that getting printed. But the exception thrown is not been printed ?

Comment: The action mettod and the validator function are been invoked, but no validation messages are been printed.

Comment: That was very helpful. In the future, please describe the problem as detailed like that instead of a nothing-saying "not working" as if you were the enduser instead of the developer. Okay, the results are not been presented in the form at all. You'd need to add `render="@form"` to the `<a4j:commandButton>` to instruct it to update the form after the request. This will update the HTML output of the `<h:form>` and thus also show any messages. I have edited the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks a million. Now another problem. I had my a4j function because that onBegin and onComplete i showed and hide a ProgressBar.How can i do that now ?

Comment: You're welcome. As to your new question, just press `Ask Question` button on right top. Don't reuse/chameleonize a different question for that.

Comment: I see that you already attempted to ask a question on that some hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996306/ajax-call-progressbar-in-jsf If you edit it into better shape, matching your current approach, then I (or anyone else) can post an answer on that.

Comment: I will close that question, this is the question i have created with my code in it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998684/show-a-waitbar-while-a-form-submits